# Error while installing mysql-server-5.1

Tags: 11.10, mysql

I need to install mysql-server-5.1 on ubuntu 11.10. While installing with apt-get I am getting

```
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.1 (--configure): subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

I have tried following things:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-common
```

rebboting the machine and again trying to install mysql by running `sudo apt-get 
install mysql-server-5.1` but no success. Still I am getting the similar error.

In SYSLOG I am getting following lines:

```
Dec 11 20:26:02 ubuntu mysqld[11272]: 111211 20:26:02  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 145554
Dec 11 20:26:02 ubuntu mysqld[11272]: 111211 20:26:02 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Dec 11 20:26:02 ubuntu mysqld[11272]: 
Dec 11 20:26:02 ubuntu mysqld[11291]: 111211 20:26:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Dec 11 20:26:02 ubuntu mysqld[11291]: 111211 20:26:02  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
Dec 11 20:26:02 ubuntu mysqld[11291]: 111211 20:26:02  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Dec 11 20:26:02 ubuntu mysqld[11291]: 111211 20:26:02  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 145554
Dec 11 20:26:02 ubuntu mysqld[11291]: 111211 20:26:02  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Dec 11 20:26:08 ubuntu mysqld[11291]: 111211 20:26:08  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 145554
Dec 11 20:26:08 ubuntu mysqld[11306]: 111211 20:26:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
Dec 11 20:26:08 ubuntu mysqld[11306]: 111211 20:26:08  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
Dec 11 20:26:08 ubuntu mysqld[11306]: 111211 20:26:08  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
Dec 11 20:26:08 ubuntu mysqld[11306]: 111211 20:26:08  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 0 145554
Dec 11 20:26:08 ubuntu mysqld[11306]: ERROR: 1050  Table 'plugin' already exists
Dec 11 20:26:08 ubuntu mysqld[11306]: 111211 20:26:08 [ERROR] Aborting
Dec 11 20:26:08 ubuntu mysqld[11306]: 
Dec 11 20:26:08 ubuntu mysqld[11306]: 111211 20:26:08  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Dec 11 20:26:13 ubuntu mysqld[11306]: 111211 20:26:13  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 145554
Dec 11 20:26:13 ubuntu mysqld[11306]: 111211 20:26:13 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Dec 11 20:26:13 ubuntu mysqld[11306]:
```

Let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: You've added a tag for 11.04, did you mean 11.10?

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server-5.1
sudo apt-get purge mysql-common
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.1
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

1. Install mysql-common first

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mysql-common
   ```
2. Install the rest of mysql

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mysql-server
   ```

Borrowed from the Ubuntu Forums [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11525596&postcount=2).

Please let me know if this helps!

Comment: Let me try the same and update you. BTW thanks for reply

Comment: I had the same problem. With the *itnet7*'s tip it works. If someone still has a problem, I suggest (in second step) to revert to the default repositories in Ubuntu Software Center / Software Sources and then repeat itnet7's help.

Comment: still I am getting the same error.

Comment: At the end I install it from source package:)

Answer (score 3):

Following the steps above, I got the same error. When I tried again, I followed the following procedure and it worked. Note that the only difference is that I installed `mysql-server-5.1` before `mysql-server`:

```
sudo apt-get remove mysql-server-5.1
sudo apt-get purge mysql-common
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-5.1
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get clean
```

Install `mysql-common` first

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-common
```

Install `mysql-server-5.1` next

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1
```

Install the rest of mysql

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer.  I upgraded from Ubuntu 11.04 to 11.10 and it hung whilst doing it's MySQL thing.  When I rebooted mysql would not start due to socket not being created/found.  Had to uninstall as per above and re-install.  Thanks very much.